# Grails Async Mail Plugin throws Hibernate Exception

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Recently, I had a use case to send a notification email in an event listener. 
I'm using grails 2.5.2, grails-async - 1.2, hibernate 3.x
Here's my event listener:

```
class ExportListenerService implements ApplicationListener<ExportNotificationEvent> {
    def bqExportService
    def asynchronousMailService

/**
 * Handle an application event.
 * @param event the event to respond to
 */

    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(ExportNotificationEvent event) {
        // get data from event

        def inParam = event.getSource() as Map

        def obj = bqExportService.generateReportAsByteArray(inParam)
        if (!obj?.generatedBytes) {

            log.error("Error Generating report ${obj.reportFileName} - No generated bytes")

        } else if (obj.generatedBytes && inParam.nextAction == 'email') {

            asynchronousMailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                to inParam?.user
                subject "Report ${obj?.reportFileName}.pdf"
                body "Your report is generated and attached with this mail."
                attachBytes "${obj?.reportFileName}.pdf", "application/pdf", obj?.generatedBytes
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
obj=[reportFileName:Execution_Export-Test_2016-02-11_06:38:03, generatedBytes:[37, 80, 10]]
| Error Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-11" 
| Error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
| Error     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:65)
| Error     at grails.plugin.hibernatehijacker.hibernate.SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.java:33)
| Error     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getCurrentSession(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:58)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:118)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.validate(AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.groovy:57)
| Error     at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailMessage.validate(AsynchronousMailMessage.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1432)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:370)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:352)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:345)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreInsert(ClosureEventListener.java:352)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:157)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:83)
| Error     at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:123)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
| Error Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-12" 
| Error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
| Error     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:65)
| Error     at grails.plugin.hibernatehijacker.hibernate.SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.java:33)
| Error     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getCurrentSession(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:58)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:118)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.validate(AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.groovy:57)
| Error     at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailAttachment.validate(AsynchronousMailAttachment.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1432)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:370)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$8.call(ClosureEventListener.java:352)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:345)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreInsert(ClosureEventListener.java:352)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreInsert(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:157)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:83)
| Error     at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:123)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-20 13:10:59,647 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] TRACE AsynchronousMailJob:104  - Entering execute method.
2016-05-20 13:10:59,655 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] DEBUG AsynchronousMailProcessService:128  - Open a new persistence session.
2016-05-20 13:10:59,664 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] TRACE AsynchronousMailProcessService:104  - Found a message: grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailMessage(id:105, to:[abhay.goel@bqurious.com], subject:Report Execution_Export-Test_2016-02-11_06:38:03.pdf, status:CREATED)
| Error Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-13" 
| Error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
| Error     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:65)
| Error     at grails.plugin.hibernatehijacker.hibernate.SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.java:33)
| Error     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getCurrentSession(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:58)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:118)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.validate(AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.groovy:57)
| Error     at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailMessage.validate(AsynchronousMailMessage.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1432)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$7.call(ClosureEventListener.java:326)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$7.call(ClosureEventListener.java:316)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:345)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreUpdate(ClosureEventListener.java:316)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreUpdate(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:166)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:91)
| Error     at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:123)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-20 13:10:59,689 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] TRACE AsynchronousMailProcessService:104  - Attempt to send the message with id=105.
2016-05-20 13:11:03,414 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] TRACE AsynchronousMailProcessService:104  - The message with id=105 was sent successfully.
| Error Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-14" 
| Error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
| Error     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:65)
| Error     at grails.plugin.hibernatehijacker.hibernate.SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionFactoryInvocationHandler.java:33)
| Error     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getCurrentSession(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:58)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:118)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.validate(AbstractHibernateGormValidationApi.groovy:57)
| Error     at grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailMessage.validate(AsynchronousMailMessage.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1432)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$7.call(ClosureEventListener.java:326)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$7.call(ClosureEventListener.java:316)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:345)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreUpdate(ClosureEventListener.java:316)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreUpdate(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:166)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:91)
| Error     at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:47)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
| Error     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:123)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-20 13:11:03,454 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] TRACE AsynchronousMailProcessService:104  - The message with id=105 was deleted.
2016-05-20 13:11:03,455 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] DEBUG AsynchronousMailProcessService:128  - Flush the persistence session.
2016-05-20 13:11:03,455 +0530 [ForkJoinPool-10-worker-1] DEBUG AsynchronousMailProcessService:128  - Destroy the persistence session.
2016-05-20 13:11:03,456 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] TRACE AsynchronousMailJob:104  - Exiting execute method. Execution time = 3808ms
2016-05-20 13:11:59,646 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] TRACE AsynchronousMailJob:104  - Entering execute method.
2016-05-20 13:11:59,657 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] TRACE AsynchronousMailJob:104  - Exiting execute method. Execution time = 10ms
2016-05-20 13:12:59,649 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-3] TRACE AsynchronousMailJob:104  - Entering execute method.
2016-05-20 13:12:59,655 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-3] TRACE AsynchronousMailJob:104  - Exiting execute method. Execution time = 6ms
2016-05-20 13:13:06,750 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] TRACE ExpiredMessagesCollectorJob:104  - Entering execute method.
2016-05-20 13:13:06,755 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] TRACE AsynchronousMailPersistenceService:104  - 0 expired messages were updated.
2016-05-20 13:13:06,757 +0530 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] TRACE ExpiredMessagesCollectorJob:104  - Exiting execute method.
201
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either wrap your code in `withTransaction` or annotate your method with `grails.transaction.Transactional` to create a Hibernate session. The second approach is probably simpler

```
class ExportListenerService implements ApplicationListener<ExportNotificationEvent> {
    def bqExportService
    def asynchronousMailService

    /**
     * Handle an application event.
     * @param event the event to respond to
     */
    @grails.transaction.Transactional
    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(ExportNotificationEvent event) {
        // get data from event

        def inParam = event.getSource() as Map

        def obj = bqExportService.generateReportAsByteArray(inParam)
        if (!obj?.generatedBytes) {

            log.error("Error Generating report ${obj.reportFileName} - No generated bytes")

        } else if (obj.generatedBytes && inParam.nextAction == 'email') {

            asynchronousMailService.sendMail {
                multipart true
                to inParam?.user
                subject "Report ${obj?.reportFileName}.pdf"
                body "Your report is generated and attached with this mail."
                attachBytes "${obj?.reportFileName}.pdf", "application/pdf", obj?.generatedBytes
            }
        }    
    }
}
```